# Chrome devtools sources displaying mostly whitespace

Tags: google-chrome, source-maps

I'm not sure why, but when trying to view files in the chrome inspector's "sources" tab, I often can only see the very smallest bit of file. Here's what it looks like:

[image: chrome source's tab all messed up]

Even with no tabs open I get a messed up view:

[image: chrome source's tab all messed up]

I've tried turning "javascript source maps" off in the settings panel and refreshing the page, but it still gives me the same weird look.

Has anyone experienced this before and if so, do they know of a solution for fixing it? It is extremely annoying...

Thank you!